# unable to render json in react component

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm having a bit of an issue rendering a JSON object in a React component.
I want to get the meaning of a random word and then render it in page.

My App.js;

```
function App() {
const [meaning,setMeaning] = useState([]);
};

useEffect(()=>{
    getMeaning()
}, [])

const getMeaning = async ()=>{
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`)
 const data = await response.json();
  setMeaning(data) 
}

<AppContext.Provider value={{word,setWord, meaning,setMeaning}}
```

my Meaning.js

```
function Meaning(){
    const{
        meaning,
        setMeaning,
    } = useContext(AppContext);

    if (!meaning.length) return <div>loading</div>

    return{meaning}
// tried return json.stringify{meaning} as well //


}
```

I do receive the object as I can console.log it.
How can I render it on page? Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can't render objects in React. You can convert the object to a string and render the string if you like

```
return (
  <div>{JSON.Stringify(meaning)}</div>
)
```

Comment: thanks very much Sean for the reply. I had indeed tried several versions of const meaning = JSON.stringify(getMeaning({word}));  and return JSON.stringify({meaning}) but nothing shows on page

Comment: Also noticing now that meaning needs to be inside an HTML element to be rendered. try        return ( <div>{JSON.Stringify(meaning)}</div>)

Comment: Please do a console and see if the data is not empty?

Comment: thanks Jerome for taking time to answer. That's the annoying thing, that the data is not empty; here is an example :
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{word: 'chase', phonetic: '/tʃeɪs/', phonetics: Array(2), meanings: Array(2), license: {…}, …}
1

Comment: @kip Seeing your fix, the issue was it not being in a valid html tag could you select my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the code a bit;
the problem was with the indexing

```
function Meaning() {
    const [meaning,setMeaning] = useState([]);
    
    const {
        correctWord
    } = useContext(AppContext)

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`)
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res)
            setMeaning(res.data[0])
            
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            
        })
        
    },[])
  return (
<div>
        <ul>
                {
                    
                    <div>
                    {meaning.word} {""}
                    <p>{meaning.phonetic}</p>
                    <p>{meaning.meanings[0]?.partOfSpeech}</p>
                    <p>{meaning.meanings[0]?.definitions[0]?.definition}</p>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                }
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

I set the function in the Meaning.js and then just called the component in the App.js.

Thanks for taking time to try and help.